# Exclude files from synctoy run

Tags: backup, synctoy

I have a family friend i set up a basic backup for them which backs up their whole user directory as a folder pair with synctoy.

However each time it runs it reports read errors on about 20-25 files and these are always profile files like ntuser.dat etc. This is expected as user is logged on.

These files we are not to bothered about as the main thing is backing up the important docs and data, but when it shows the errors it gives you option to untick to exclude, but next time you run the sync the same files fail again.

What im wondering is if there is anyway of deselecting certain files from the backup? or is it going to be a case of setting up lots of folder pairs, eg, docs, pics, favorites, music etc would rather avoid this just in case the user ends up putting data in the root of their user folder or an app creates a folder there.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the opening window there is an option to "Change Options". Click on that to bring up a window with "Files to include:", "Files to exclude" so excluding *.dat files should solve the problem.
I use it to backup "My Documents", action "contribute" and so far have not had to exclude any files as there have been no errors.

Comment: thanks will give that a try tonight should do pretty much what i need also noticed system files which should be good to exclude as well.